# Is there an easier way to show that a kite has perpendicular diagonals using scalar products?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I want to use scalar products to prove that a kite has perpendicular diagonals.

My attempt : Let $a,b,c,d$ vectors with $a+b+c+d=0$ and $a^2=d^2$ and $b^2=c^2$

Then, we get $$(a+b)(a+d)=a^2+ab+ad+bd=d^2+ab+ad+bd=ab-cd$$

The expression $(a+b)(a+d)$ can be rewritten as $$(-c-d)(-b-c)=c^2+bc+cd+bd=b^2+bc+cd+bd=-ab+cd$$. So, we get $ab-cd=-(ab-cd)$, hence
$ab-cd=0$. So, $(a+b)(a+d)=0$

But this proof is cumbersome and not very intuitive. Is there an easier
way ?

Comment: Not all kites have perpendicular diagonals.

Comment: @EmilioNovati You are wrong, all kites (mathematical ones anyway) have perpendicular diagonals.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge of English. I did not know that the term had a precise mathematical meaning.